# YouTube fullscreen moves html5 elements

Tags: html, youtube-api, fullscreen

I am using an iframe to play youtube videos:

```
    var iframe = '<iframe src="' + src + '?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '"></iframe>';
```

image before the defect:

http://s21.postimg.org/7zpp2kmrp/image.png

The thing is that when I click the fullscreen button and then I press Esc or click the shrink button... all the elements go up on the screen. I found that top and left properties are changing from 0 to random numbers.

image of the defect:

http://s1.postimg.org/v7vqdf9jh/image.png

I found a static solution for this, it works but it's really nasty so I would prefer to not use my fix.

I would like to know if somebody have had the same issue as me or if anyone knows if there's something wrong with https:// www.youtube.com/iframe_api. 
(remove space)

This only happens in google chrome.

Comment: images you provided are not supported for stackoverflow, please change format.  (you cannot insert it into post, but others can)

Comment: It's really hard to say without more additional context. Could you share code snippets of page, including HTML, CSS and JS used?

Comment: Hi Miki! thanks for telling me this, the post didn't show me the broken links but I see them now. The first image is: http://postimg.org/image/pczzhfi2r/ and the second one http://postimg.org/image/kl1x801e3/

Comment: Hi herrbischoff! I know is not much information, but it is all I can show.... the company I work for doesn't let me show more.... but I just wanted to know if anyone has experienced any troubles like this embedding youtube videos... because in my "fix" I run 2 intervals.... and ... well... I better not use that.

Comment: Without context it is quite impossible to tell why this is happening. How about creating a really broken down version of the page where the issue still comes up and putting that on a Codepen or the like? I'd take a shot at fixing the problem then.

Comment: I have set up a Codepen with a bare-bones setup derived from your images. I don't see the problem occurring there: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdOJGZ

Comment: Hi again herrbischoff! After many testings and see your example,  I'll have to talk to the UX team then. Thanks a lot for the test in Codepen! really helped a lot!